# how can i share a list from one js to another?

Tags: javascript

thanks for everyone who heloed me today already. i was told to use a storage to share the info and... well it didnt work.

***I need to share the list that user made from list.js to dragANDdrop.js. from dragANDdrop.js i want to show this on html. well the list is not showing, i can't get why so***

here is what i tried
list.js

```
localStorage.setItem('lst', list);
```

dragANDdrop.js

```
list = localStorage.getItem('lst');
const html = list.map((item) => `<li>${item}</li>`).join('');
document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = html;
```

the second part should display the list on the html page.

dragANDdrop.html

```
<section class="home-section">
    <div class="home-content">
        <i class='bx bx-menu' ></i>
        <span class="text"><h1>To do list</h1></span>
        <ul></ul>  
    </div>
</section>
<script src="list.js"></script>
<script src="dragANDdrop.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Additionally, please see [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: *As a guess*... `setItem` expects a string, and `getItem` returns a string.  Based on the usage of the latter, it sounds like you may be trying to store an array as a string.  You may be looking to [serialize to JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) when storing, and deserialize when fetching from storage.

Comment: "i was told to use a storage to share the info" and did you research (read the docs) the storage api before delving into it so that you know what to do? Such as realize that the datatype is string.

Comment: to set: `my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']; localStorage.setItem("lst", JSON.stringify(my_list));`; to retrieve: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lst"))`

Comment: Also... It's not clear to me why you're using `localStorage` in the first place, given the code shown.  Both of these JavaScript files are being executed on the same page.  They can see the same global variables.  Unless this data needs to survive a page refresh or be visible to other pages, `localStorage` seems like overkill just to read a value from a variable.  If the `list` variable is in global/window scope (we don't know) then the code in `dragANDdrop.js` can already see that variable and just use it directly.  What stops that from working?

Comment: i can't be sure what actually breaks everything. maybe the code which sends the list to html doesnt work properly even though i have tried different options that i have found

Comment: @vbhnjk: *"i can't be sure what actually breaks"* - This is a good time to start familiarizing yourself with your browser's debugging tools.  If there are any runtime errors, they should be visible on the browser's development console.  The browser's script debugger can be used to place breakpoints in the code and step through the code line by line as it executes, observing the runtime values and behaviors.  Failing that, you could even just log useful information to the console and observe that information to see if it's what you expected from running the code.

Comment: for now i've stopped on this `var lst = list

function myFunction() {
  var result = "";
  lst.forEach(function (item) {
    result += "<li>" + item;
  });
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
myFunction(lst)` but it doesnt work. html: `<section class="home-section">
        <div class="home-content">
            <i class='bx bx-menu' ></i>
            <span class="text"><h1>To do list</h1></span>
            <p><ol id="demo"></ol></p>

        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="list.js"></script>
    <script src="dragANDdrop.js"></script>`

Comment: thanks for mentioning console! now i see that it can't see the properties. well, as i got, the list is empty. i'll try to work on it, thank you again i am really new to all this stuff